# Expresso Store pagination

Tags: expresso-store

How do I enable pagination in the {store:orders} tag? I tried:

```
{exp:store:orders member_id='CURRENT_USER' order_by='order_date' sort='desc' pagination="bottom"}
.... snip ....
{paginate}
    <p>{pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:store:orders}
```

But it just outputs the paginate tags as they appear in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue also but managed to work around it using the query module. Query module does support paginate and I have also used an INNER JOIN to get our product titles. Here is my code:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_store_orders INNER JOIN exp_store_order_items ON exp_store_orders.id=exp_store_order_items.order_id WHERE member_id = {exp:stash:get name='member_id'} AND exp_store_orders.order_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY order_date DESC" parse="inward" limit="7" paginate="bottom"}
    {if no_results}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">You haven't placed any orders yet!</td>
        </tr>
    {/if}
    <tr>
        <th><a href="/orders/{exp:zoo_visitor:details member_id='{member_id}'}{member:url_title}/{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}{id}" title="More Information">#{id}</a></th>
        <td>{title}</td>
        <td>{order_date {sn_date_default}}</td>
        <td><span class="payment-status {order_status_name}">{exp:heading_title:heading_case}{order_status_name}{/exp:heading_title:heading_case}</span></td>
        <td>{order_total}</td>
        <td>{exp:zoo_visitor:details member_id="{member_id}"}{visitor:member_title} {visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}</td>
        <td><a href="/orders/{exp:zoo_visitor:details member_id='{member_id}'}{member:url_title}/{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}{id}" title="More Information" class="icon"><span class="icon-circle-right"></span><span class="visually-hidden">More Information</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    {paginate}
        <tr>
            <td>{pagination_links}</td>
        </tr>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:query}
```

I am using stash so that users can only see their own orders, but also the manager of the company they belong to taken from a relationship field can view the orders also. The rest are just standard variables that you would usually use from the {store_orders} tag.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, it appears that the Store Orders tag doesn't support pagination at present.